# PhoneGap Build with OneSignal not working

Tags: phonegap-build, onesignal

I'm using PhoneGap Build with OneSignal but it is not working. It shows only the first alert message.

Here is the code:
https://github.com/claudiosw/ZumitApp/

And you can download the app here:
https://build.phonegap.com/apps/2193000/builds

Also pasting the code here:

File config.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.zumitapp" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">

    <name>ZumitApp</name>
    <description>Tenha Mais Resultados</description>
    <author email="claudiosw@" href="http://zumitapp.com/App">Claudio Shigueo Watanabe</author>

    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-6.3.0" />
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device" />

    <preference name="orientation"                value="portrait" />       <!-- all: default means both landscape and portrait are enabled -->

    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media-capture" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.contacts" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.vibration" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" />
    <!--gap:plugin name="com.simplec.plugins.localnotification" /-->
        <!--plugin name="com.onesignal.plugins.onesignal" spec="1.5.0" source="pgb" /-->
        <!--plugin name="com.onesignal.plugins.onesignal" spec="1.9.0" source="pgb" /-->
        <gap:plugin name="onesignal-cordova-plugin-pgb-compat" source="npm" /> 
        <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-googleplayservices" source="npm" /> 
        <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-android-support-v4" source="npm" />
<!--gap:plugin name="onesignal-cordova-plugin" source="npm" /-->

<!-- Recommend the newest cli but requires cli-5.1.1+ and gradle for Android. -->
<!-- If the below settings are not compatible with your project set the "PGB ANT" version above. -->
<!--preference name="android-build-tool" value="gradle" /-->


    <icon src="icon.png" />

    <icon src="res/icons/ios/Icon.png" gap:platform="ios" width="57" height="57" />
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/Icon@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="114" height="114" />    
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/Icon-72.png" gap:platform="ios" width="72" height="72" />
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/Icon-72@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="144" height="144" />

    <icon src="res/icons/android/drawable-ldpi/Icon.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
    <icon src="res/icons/android/drawable-mdpi/Icon.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icons/android/drawable-hdpi/Icon.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icons/android/drawable-xdpi/Icon.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" />

    <gap:splash src="ZumitApp_grande.jpg" />

    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/drawable-ldpi/splash.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/drawable-mdpi/splash.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/drawable-hdpi/splash.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/drawable-xdpi/splash.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" />

    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/Default.png" gap:platform="ios" width="320" height="480" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="680" height="960" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/Deafult-568h-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="1136" />

    <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="true" />
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" subdomains="true" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
</widget>
```

File index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>ZumitApp</title>
    <script src="phonegap.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false); 
function onDeviceReady() {
            // Now safe to use the Codova API

  // Enable to debug issues.
  alert("teste0");
  window.plugins.OneSignal.setLogLevel({logLevel: 4, visualLevel: 4});
  alert("teste1");

  var notificationOpenedCallback = function(jsonData) {
    console.log('didReceiveRemoteNotificationCallBack: ' + JSON.stringify(jsonData));
  };
alert("teste2");
  window.plugins.OneSignal.init("22a70849-091e-4eca-8b5b-e7fc5821f95b",
                                 {googleProjectNumber: "428050097085"},
                                 notificationOpenedCallback);
  alert("teste3");
  // Show an alert box if a notification comes in when the user is in your app.
  window.plugins.OneSignal.enableInAppAlertNotification(true);
  //alert("teste4");
     window.location="http://zumitapp.com/App"; 
//alert("teste5");
}
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <header class="bar bar-nav">
      <h1 class="title">Boas-vindas ao ZumitApp</h1>
    </header>

    <h2>Aguarde. Carregando...</h2>


  </body>
</html>
```

I have tried to debug but it didn't worked out. Maybe it is because my smartphone is old (LG-P705) or the desktop (Windows Vista).

Thanks you very much!

Comment: Can you try removing the following line?
 `window.location="http://zumitapp.com/App";` 
It could be directing before finishing. Also I recommend inlineing your function or moving `document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false); ` below it.

Comment: Thanks, @jkasten!
Unfortunutely it haven't solved the problem.
And my app is remote.
Would be it better to open it in a iframe or I could try another solution?
As it is printing just the first message, the problem would be in this line. Any idea why?

    window.plugins.OneSignal.setLogLevel({logLevel: 4, visualLevel: 4});

Comment: Could you expanded on "my app is remote"? You must make a full build of your app (APK / .IPA) as OneSignal uses native code. When `window.location` is set to an external URL the OneSignal SDK will stop working. You can use an iframe as you suggested instead.

Comment: Ok. I will try to use iframe.
But even without the window.location, the problem is the same.
It seems that this line is not working:

    window.plugins.OneSignal.setLogLevel({logLevel: 4, visualLevel: 4});

Any other idea?

Comment: The device's `logcat` should show some warnings or errors. Can you check it? You can share the full log as a txt file with OneSignal support if you need help looking it over.

Comment: Thanks, @jkasten! 
Couldn't find logcat. While I was searching for that I discovered that I could try to use an Android Simulator to debug better. Couldn't make it work yet but I hope that I can until tomorrow.